Объединить два запроса mySQL
Есть две таблицы. Первая с городами, вторая с именами людей. Нужно взять 10 рандомных имён людей, и к каждому добавить рандомный город. Должен получиться массив: Максим - Москва, Наташа - Новосибирск, и т.д. По отдельности запросы такие:
SELECT username FROM table_users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
SELECT cityname FROM table_cities ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10

Помогите, пожалуйста, объединить их для получения вышеописанного результата?
UPD У меня единственный вариант на php - взять массив городов, и каждую его итерацию присваивать элементу (городу) рандомное имя. Но это 10 лищних запросов в БД, да ещё и by rand.

А какой-нибудь ROW_NUM там нет? Тогда можно было бы его тоже заселектить и сделать JOIN этих двух таблиц по этому номеру, да и всё.

@CrazyElf  там и у городов и у имён есть уникальный id. Если вы об этом. Вы имеете в виду, каждому человеку будет соответствовать конкретный город по id? Так не пойдёт)

Не, Id из таблицы не подойдёт. В нормальных БД бывает нумерация строк именно самого селекта. Я кратко погуглил, похоже в MySql такого нет, надо как-то исхитряться, чтобы пересчитать строки.

Не понял про 10 лишних запросов. Кто мешает сделать два запроса и склеить два результатирующих массива в один?

@AlexeyTen мешает моя необразованность и темнота)) Я именно об этом и спрашиваю. Как сделать?

Точная версия MySQL?

@ЕрмекИбраев https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php

Ну например так:
SELECT username,
       ( SELECT cityname 
         FROM table_cities 
         ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
         ) AS cityname
FROM table_users 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10

Правда, такой запрос не гарантирует 10 разных городов.

Ну это как-то грязновато, действительно города могут и повториться )

@CrazyElf Я ориентируюсь на слова автора - а у него за уникальность городов нет ни полслова. Так-то понятно - ROW_NUMBER.

В вашей ситуации будет проще сделать объединение на PHP.
Т.е. получить в один массив 10 имен пользователей, а во второй 10 городов. Т.е. те два запроса, котоыре вы приводите. Выполняете их отдельно и получаете два массива по 10 элементов каждый.
А затем в PHP объединяете их. Например, так
//В массивах $users и $cities результат запросов.
$result = [];
foreach($users AS $index => $row) {
    $result[] = ['username' => $row['username'], 
                 'cityname' => $cities[$index]['cityname']
                ];
}

Т.е. подразумевается, что в исходных массивах данные уже перемешены случайно и поэтому дополнительного рандома не нужно.
